# Generic function returning map

Tags: generics, ada

In the following example a ordered map is created and returned by a function:

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure Main is
   package My_Map is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
     (Key_Type     => Natural,
      Element_Type => Unbounded_String);

   function Create_Map return My_Map.Map is
      Map_Instance : My_Map.Map;
   begin
      Map_Instance.Insert (1, To_Unbounded_String ("Foo"));
      Map_Instance.Insert (2, To_Unbounded_String ("Bar"));

      return Map_Instance;
   end Create_Map;
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

I would like to know if it is possible to convert the function `Create_Map` to a more generic one? The following code shows my idea but unfortunately I don't really know the correct formal types `???`:

```ada
   generic
      type Key_Type is ???;
      type Element_Type is ???;
      type Map_Type is ???;
   function Create_Map_Generic return Map_Type is
      Map_Instance : Map_Type;
   begin
      -- Inserts calls would be based on parsing data ...

      return Map_Instance;
   end;

   package My_Map_One is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
     (Key_Type     => Natural,
      Element_Type => Unbounded_String);

   function Create_Map_One is new Create_Map_Generic
     (Key_Type     => Natural,
      Element_Type => Unbounded_String,
      Map_Type     => My_Map_One.Map);

   package My_Map_Two is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
     (Key_Type     => Unbounded_String,
      Element_Type => Positive);

   function Create_Map_Two is new Create_Map_Generic
     (Key_Type     => Unbounded_String,
      Element_Type => Positive,
      Map_Type     => My_Map_Two.Map);
```

The formal types `Key_Type` and `Element_Type` are specified twice (package declaration and the instantiation of the generic function). Could these be extracted from the declaration of the package itself?

Comment: It might be _possible_, but I’m afraid I can’t see why you’d want to

Comment: To avoid code duplication. In my program such maps are filled from parsed input files but the types differ based on the input file kind. At the moment I duplicated the parsing code multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure that this answers your use case, but here goes ..

I don’t think you can do this with just a generic function; I think it’d be better as a generic package (to declare the map, from e.g. `Positive` to `Unbounded_String`) containing a generic function to create maps using a specific population subprogram.

The outer generic:

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps;
generic
   type Key_Type is private;
   type Element_Type is private;
   with function "<" (Left, Right : Key_Type) return Boolean is <>;
   with function "=" (Left, Right : Element_Type) return Boolean is <>;
package Maps_G is
   package Maps is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
     (Key_Type     => Key_Type,
      Element_Type => Element_Type,
      "<"          => "<",
      "="          => "=");
   subtype Map is Maps.Map;
   generic
      with procedure Populate (The_Map : in out Map);
   function Create_Map return Map;
end Maps_G;
```

and its body:

```ada
package body Maps_G is
   function Create_Map return Map is
   begin
      return M : Map do
         Populate (M);
      end return;
   end Create_Map;
end Maps_G;
```

with a little test program:

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Maps_G;
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Test is
   package P_To_UBS_Maps is new Maps_G (Key_Type     => Positive,
                                        Element_Type => Unbounded_String);
   procedure Populate (The_Map : in out P_To_UBS_Maps.Map) is
   begin
      The_Map.Insert (42, To_Unbounded_String ("the answer"));
      The_Map.Insert (1, To_Unbounded_String ("one"));
   end Populate;
   function Create
     is new P_To_UBS_Maps.Create_Map (Populate);
   M : P_To_UBS_Maps.Map := Create;
begin
   for J in M.Iterate loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (P_To_UBS_Maps.Maps.Key (J)'Image
                              & " -> "
                              & To_String (P_To_UBS_Maps.Maps.Element (J)));
   end loop;
end Test;
```

Build & run:

```
$ gnatmake test -f -g
gcc -c -g test.adb
gcc -c -g maps_g.adb
gnatbind -x test.ali
gnatlink test.ali -g
gnatlink: warning: executable name "test" may conflict with shell command
$ ./test
 1 -> one
 42 -> the answer
```

---

That done, there seems no real advantage over just calling `Populate` directly.

Answer (score 4):

Simon gave the better more complete answer.  I am just providing an alternative where the map package is passed in as a formal parameter instead.  To do this, you can pass the package as a formal parameter as long as it's parameters are also sent as formal parameters:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps;

procedure Hello is

    generic
        type Key_Type is private;
        type Element_Type is private;
        with function "<"(L,R : Key_Type) return Boolean is <>;
        with function "="(L,R : Key_Type) return Boolean is <>;

        with package Map_Package is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
            (Key_Type     => Key_Type,
             Element_Type => Element_Type,
             "<"          => "<",
             "="          => "=");
    function Create_Map_Generic return Map_Package.Map;        

    function Create_Map_Generic return Map_Package.Map is
    begin
        return Result : Map_Package.Map do
            null;  -- replace with your input based creation
        end return;
    end Create_Map_Generic;

    -- Just a nonsense type to test out compilation
    type My_Key is null record;
    function "<"(L,R : My_Key) return Boolean is (True);
    function "="(L,R : My_Key) return Boolean is (True);

    package Maps is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
        (Key_Type     => My_Key,
         Element_Type => Integer);

    function Create is new Create_Map_Generic
        (Key_Type     => My_Key,
         Element_Type => Integer,
         Map_Package  => Maps);

begin
  Put_Line("Hello, world!");
end Hello;
```

As a bonus additional tidbit, IF you don't care what the key and element types are inside the function (I think you do, but just incase), then you don't have to specify them and can simply do:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps;

procedure Hello is

    generic
        with package Map_Package is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
            (others => <>);
    function Create_Map_Generic return Map_Package.Map;        

    function Create_Map_Generic return Map_Package.Map is
    begin
        return Result : Map_Package.Map do
            null;  -- replace with your input based creation
        end return;
    end Create_Map_Generic;

    -- Just a nonsense type to test out compilation
    type My_Key is null record;
    function "<"(L,R : My_Key) return Boolean is (True);
    function "="(L,R : My_Key) return Boolean is (True);

    package Maps is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
        (Key_Type     => My_Key,
         Element_Type => Integer);

    function Create is new Create_Map_Generic
        (Map_Package  => Maps);

begin
  Put_Line("Hello, world!");
end Hello;
```

You can also compromise in the middle depending on what you want to use in your creation function:

```ada
generic
    type Key_Type is private;
    type Element_Type is private;
    with package Map_Package is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
        (Key_Type     => Key_Type,
         Element_Type => Element_Type,
         others       => <>);
function Create_Map_Generic return Map_Package.Map;
```

Comment: Actually, when you use the `with package P is new G (others => <>);` syntax, you can reference the generic formals of P to access the actual parameters used to instantiate the package supplied for P: `Key : P.Key_Type;".